# Pass data by CommandParameter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to pass **UserName** by `CommandParameter`.

```
<GridViewColumn   Width="Auto" Header="UserName" >
   <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="..." CommandParameter="{Binding Path=UserName}"></Button>                                                                                                         </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

But here I am not sure what do I have to use to catch it...

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // How to get UserName  here?
}
```

Any clue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best you can do with such approach is this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button) sender;
    var userName = button.CommandParameter;
}
```

Though it will do the job but it is not how `CommandParameter` is supposed to be used. `CommandParameter` is supposed to be passed as parameter to button's command. So if you will use `Command` instead of handling `Button.Click` your command will receive your data in its `Execute` and `CanExecute` handlers. See samples for commands&buttons in google. Here is first link from google for example: [How to use Commands in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238657/How-to-use-Commands-in-WPF)

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use the click handler, why not bind the Button's Tag property to UserName? A little more along the lines of what the Tag property was intended than a misuse of Commanding principals.

```
<Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Button Content" Tag="{Binding UserName}"/>

private void Button_Click(object Sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var Button = (Button)Sender;
    var UserName = (string)Button.Tag;
}
```